# adding a class on to an element via mouse hover using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make buttons where each has mouse hover effects,I can't seem to figured out while hovered on a `button` I want to add a css class onto them so that an animation would take effect.

this is my css class I want to call .player

```
.playerside {
animation: myframe 0.3s ease-in-out 0.5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes myframe {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
}
50% {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
80% {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
}
```

this is what I have tried so far on javascript, I always get a console error
 `"rps.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.displaychoice (rps.js:10)"`

```
const gameManager =
{
    choices: document.querySelectorAll('.choices'),
    displaymsg: function (e)
    {
        console.log(e.target.id);
    },
    displaychoice: function (e)
    {
        e.classList.add('darken');
    }
}
gameManager.choices.forEach(index => index.addEventListener('click', gameManager.displaymsg));
gameManager.choices.forEach(index => index.addEventListener('mouseover', gameManager.displaychoice));
```

Comment: e.classList.add must be e.target.classList.add()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to access `.classList.add()` on an event. Remember e is the event, and you must still get the target from that event and then access `classList.add`.

```
displaychoice: function (e)
{
    e.target.classList.add('darken'); //SOLUTION
}
```